# Lightbox function from live jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have an image gallery that dynamically calls new images using jQuery, i want to lightbox these images if they are clicked.

The problem is it seems as though the elements aren't being called by the jQuery because they need to be live calls.

What I originally tried is this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.ad-image').lightBox();
});
```

and what i tried after, which still doesnt work is this:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click','a.ad-image',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).lightBox();
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Lightbox: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: What is the code to dynamically call these new images? It is there that you should use lightbox() to reinit your configuration.

Comment: its a gallery plugin, ive altered it to have the proper class and href, that would work with lightbox if it wasnt dynamically added.

Comment: Just a thought, but in the second block of code you initialize the `.lightBox()` function, not trigger it.  Maybe try adding a `$(this).click()` after you initialize it?  If this works, it's not necessarily the best solution; try @Panagiotis's idea first.

Comment: @Panagiotis it is a plugin, that i have modified a little bit, but what would an example of how to reinit the configuration be?

Comment: Does it have a success function on load() or on bringing ajax data? If so, after loading the images, put the .lightbox() call.